# in Foxpro the difference between currency and number datatype

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

What is difference between number and currency as data type, and how is it treated internally by Fox-pro.

Comment: Which version of FoxPro?

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

On disk (as fields of a DBF), NUMERIC fields store the ASCII representation of the number, including the sign and decimal point. CURRENCY fields store the 64bit INTEGER that is the number.

When used in calculations (in memory), CURRENCY values are still 64bit INTEGER amounts but the FLOAT or NUMERIC are implemented as IEEE Floating Point numbers.

To most people, what's important is that integer math never loses precision, whereas this can become a problem with floating point math.